# An Introductory Question on Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-sum

I am a beginner at Riemann Integration and before I delve deeper into the subject, I would like it to be verified that I understand the working processes. Here is the question:

**Consider a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ defined as follows: $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x)=x^3$ if $x$ is irrational. Compute $U(f),L(f)$ and check if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.**

My solution is as follows. Please verify if it is correct.:

**First we evaluate $U(f)$ as it is straightforward. Take a partition $P=\{x_i: i=0,1,...,n\}$ with $x_i=\dfrac{i}{n}$. Now $U(P,f)=\sum \sup\{f(x):x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]\}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_0^{n-1}\dfrac{(i+1)^2}{n^2}=\dfrac{\sum_1^ni^2}{n^3}\to\dfrac{1}{3}=U(f)$**

**Next to evaluate $L(f)$ take a partition $P=\{\dfrac{i}{n+\sqrt{2}}:i=0,1,...,n\}\cup\{1\}$.** I chose this so that $||P||\to 0$ as $P$ is refined. **$L(P,f)=\sum\inf\{f(x):x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]\}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\dfrac{\sum_0^{n-1}\dfrac{i^3}{(n+\sqrt{2})^3}}{n+\sqrt{2}}+(\dfrac{n}{n+\sqrt{2}})^3(1-\dfrac{n}{n+\sqrt{2}})=\dfrac{(n-1)^2n^2}{4(n+\sqrt{2})^4}+(\dfrac{n}{n+\sqrt{2}})^3(1-\dfrac{n}{n+\sqrt{2}})\to\dfrac{1}{4}+0=\dfrac{1}{4}=L(f)$**

**Hence $U(f)\neq L(f)$ so $f$ is not Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$.**

Comment: Why such a weird partition? The same partition works even in case of $L(f)$. Remember you are taking the infimum in that case. Also what definition of reimann integrable, you are following? If you are following the [Darboux integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) definition, then you have to be more rigorous, since you haven't shown it for a general partition.

Comment: The reason for such a weird partition is that, suppose we take the same partition $x_i=i/n$. Then there arises some problems in computing the infimum values. $i/n$ is rational, but there may be some irrational number in $[i/n,(i+1)/n]$ such that cube of that irrational number < $i^2/n^2$. I don't think that we can determine $L(P,f)$ easily in that case, it will only lead to more messy caseworks and inequalities. Note that $i/(n+\sqrt{2})$ works more effectively. The idea was the make the bounds of each interval irrational.

Comment: I computed using the Darboux integral definition. But where is the rigor lacking? Indeed, I am refining my partition as n goes to infinity, so $U(P,f)\to U(f)$ and $L(P,f)\to L(f)$. Maybe because I didn't PROVE that the sequences $U(P_n,f)$ and $L(P_n,f)$ are tending to some infimum and some supremum respectively, this could be objectionable. But the main idea is partitioning and then reducing the norm i.e. length of the largest subinterval. This is achieved in both the partitions.

Comment: Okay, so Darboux Integral definition relies on using a GENERAL partition? Like not defining the partition at all? But in this case, would it not be easier to start with a partition, then refine it? Sorry but I am not yet fully familiar with the intricacies of rigor in this new topic, so please help me out. :D :)

Comment: You can show that $\inf\{f([\frac{i}n,\frac{i+1}n])\}=\frac{i^3}{n^3}$. Since you can always get a sequence of irrational numbers converging to $\frac{i}n$, and hence it's $f$-value goes to $\frac{i^3}{n^3}$. Showing that for a equidistant partition $P_n$ with $n+1$ points, $U(P_n,f) \to \frac13$, does not prove that $\inf U(P,f)=\frac13$, since there may be some typical partition $P'$ for which $U(P',f)<\frac13$. There is a certain result that ensures such existence of $P'$ is not possible. However, it is also possible without the aid of that result, to complete the proof by a simple trick.

Comment: If you want to compute the upper and lower integrals just from the definition, a simple recipe would be

1) Guess the value of upper integral say $u$

2) Show that $U(P,f)\ge u$ for every partition $P$

3) Take a specific sequence of partition $\{Q_n\}$ (usually equidistant one). Show that $U(Q_n,f)\to u$.

Do the analogue for lower integral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18888/discussion-between-sayan-and-aranya-dey).

Comment: Thank you Sayan da. I would rather not enter Chat because LATEX is not visible there. But I have got the idea of the proof. Going by your second last comment, I think I missed Step 2.